# Creating 100% Stackbar

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, anaconda, jupyter-notebook, pandas-groupby

I'm new at creating graphs using matplotlib and I am wondering how to create "100% stackbar" chart.

Here's my Code on pulling out the dataframe that I want to have created with 100% staked bar:

```
data_stack = data.groupby(["assigned_cluster", "Job_Collar"]).size().unstack()
```

Here's
my DataFrame:

```
    Blue    Gold     Pink     White
0   6584.0  NaN      22770.0  NaN
1   NaN     239.0    NaN      1939.0
2   NaN     241.0    NaN      1.0
3   NaN     15.0     NaN      NaN
4   7998.0  NaN      3.0    1754.0
```

My Attempt to create 100% Stackbar:

```
data_stack.plot(kind='barh', stacked=True, figsize=(18.5, 10.5))
```

Also, I need help with assigning color per bar segment (blue = blue, gold = gold, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

Try `color = [your colors]`

```
data_stack.plot(kind='barh', stacked=True, figsize=(18.5, 10.5),color=['blue','gold','pink','lightgrey'])
```

Comment: Thanks! It did worked, I'm currently trying color maps now :) Can you also help me with creating 100% stacked bar?

Comment: @Marcus You already have the stacked plot right? What is your required output?

Comment: It is a stack bar but if I visualize the dataframe, some of the bars will look small because the some of the rows has extreme values